# The numbers from $11111$ to $99999$ are written in a random order, one after another, forming a single number. Prove that it cannot be a power of $2$.

Tags: divisibility, perfect-powers

I found the following problem in a book with advanced math problems for 6th grade that I cannot solve:

> All the numbers from $11111$ to $99999$ are written in a random order, one after another, thus forming a single number with $444445$ digits. Prove that regardless what the resulting number is, it cannot be a power of $2$.

I tried various things but could not find any solution.

One of my ideas was to determine the sum of all its digits.
11111 & 99999 = 1+1+1+1+1 + 9+9+9+9+9 = 50
11112 & 99998 = 1+1+1+1+2 + 9+9+9+9+8 = 50
...
55555 = 25

So we have 44444 pairs whose sum of digits is 50 and un unpaired number, 55555 whose sum of digits is 25.

Therefore, the sum of all the digits is 44444 * 50 + 25 = 2222225.

However, I don't know how to prove that no power of 2 has the sum of its digits equal to 2222225.

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: If the digitsum would be divisible by $3$ , we would be done. Here, I have no idea for a proof. (6th grade ?)

Comment: Ah, I think I have an idea now. There are not many powers of $2$ with the given number of digits !

Comment: You're on the right track. Try a different modulus which is invariant.

Comment: @Peter, yes, this is 6th grade math in Romania. Well, it's difficult problems for competitions, so not for ordinary 6th graders. But still, can't use used more than powers, sum of digits, divisibility rules, prime factorization or others similar things to prove it.

Comment: My calculations about the sum of all digits is wrong. I now see. eg. 11120 & 99990 don't have the sum 50.

Comment: Fwiw, the actual digital sum is $2054321=59\times34819$.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $10 ^5 - 1 = 99999 = 9 \times 11111$.

**Hint:** Show that the resulting number is a multiple of $11111$, hence is not a power of 2.

---

Phrased in modular arithmetic, there is an easy proof (just work through it). The difficulty is expressing that to a 6th grader (and expecting them to come up with it).

> Let $f(i)$ denote which position $i$ appears in.
>  Then, $S = \sum_{i=11111}^{99999} i 10^{5 f(i) }$.
>  Since $ 10^5 - 1 = 99999$, so $10^{5f(i) } \equiv 1 \pmod{99999}$ and $ S \equiv \sum_{i=11111}^{99999} i \pmod{99999}$.
>  This is an invariant, which strongly suggests that we study it and work modulo a factor of 99999.
>
>  When summing up the arithmetic progression, observe that $11111 + 99999 = 11111 \times 10 $.
>  Hence, $ S \equiv 0 \pmod{11111}$, so cannot be a power of 2.

This also explains why trying modulo $3$ or $9$ didn't immediately work. However, if we added in the terms $10000$ to $11110$, then mod 3 would work. This version would have been a great question for a 6th grader.

This generalizes as follows: The concatenation of terms from $\frac{10^n - 1} { 9} $ to $10^n - 1$ in any order is a multiple of $ \frac{10^n-1}{9}$, hence never a power of 2.

Comment: I realized I miscomputed the sum of all digits. It's not 2222225 as I said. For instance, 11112 and 99990 don't have the sum of digits 50 as I said. I'm trying to follow your proof. But I don't get the first sum.

Comment: @MariusBancila Right, your digit sum doesn't work out, but the digit root (iterated digit sum) does, and that's sufficient for the rule of 3, 9.   $\quad$ Which first sum are you talking about? The expression for $S$? That's just splitting up the resulting number into the component integers, EG $111115555599999 = 11111\times 10^{10} + 55555\times 10^5 + 99999$.

Comment: Right. I was getting confused by `f(i)`, because I was thinking least significant position (if `11111` is the first then `f(11111) = 1`), which in fact is most significant position (if `11111` is the first then `f(11111) = 88889`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use digital sums, but there is a subtle trick.

In base 10, the sum of digits rule works modulo $10-1=9$. More generally in base $b$, it works modulo $b-1$.

Let $b=10^5$ so that each "digit" from $11111$ through $99999$ is represented as a single digit of our number base $10^5$. In this rendering the sum of digits must be a multiple of $55555$, for this is the average of all the "digits" in our selected base $10^5$.

Now $10^5-1$ is a multiple of $11111$, so the digit-sum test works for that divisor, and we have just seen that the digit sum of the given number is divisible by $55555=5×11111$. So our number is a multiple of $11111$, which is impossible for a power of $2$!

We can go further. The smallest prime factor of $11111$ is $41$, so if our long number is to be a perfect power at all the base must be at least $41$. Since $11111$ is square-free, we can increase this bound to $11111$ itself.